# esp32-cam stuck in repeat boot

Tags: esp32, bootloader, networking, camera

I am trying to bring the esp32 example code live. I am able to upload the image error free but when I remove the jumper and then press the reset switch, instead of seeing it logon to my network via serial monitor, I just get this repeating over and over and over again.

```
rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1216
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40078000,len:9720
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40080400,len:6352
entry 0x400806b8

Brownout detector was triggered

ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1216
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40078000,len:9720
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40080400,len:6352
entry 0x400806b8

Brownout detector was triggered

ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1216
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40078000,len:9720
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40080400,len:6352
entry 0x400806b8

Brownout detector was triggered

ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1216
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40078000,len:9720
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40080400,len:6352
entry 0x400806b8
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
```

How do I boot an esp32-cam correctly?

code:

```
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include <WiFi.h>

//
// WARNING!!! Make sure that you have either selected ESP32 Wrover Module,
//            or another board which has PSRAM enabled
//

// Select camera model
//#define CAMERA_MODEL_WROVER_KIT
//#define CAMERA_MODEL_ESP_EYE
//#define CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_PSRAM
//#define CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_WIDE
#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER

#include "camera_pins.h"

const char* ssid = "getAjobFool";
const char* password = "andreasd1";

void startCameraServer();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
  Serial.println();

  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
  //init with high specs to pre-allocate larger buffers
  if(psramFound()){
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 10;
    config.fb_count = 2;
  } else {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 12;
    config.fb_count = 1;
  }

#if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_ESP_EYE)
  pinMode(13, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(14, INPUT_PULLUP);
#endif

  // camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }

  sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
  //initial sensors are flipped vertically and colors are a bit saturated
  if (s->id.PID == OV3660_PID) {
    s->set_vflip(s, 1);//flip it back
    s->set_brightness(s, 1);//up the blightness just a bit
    s->set_saturation(s, -2);//lower the saturation
  }
  //drop down frame size for higher initial frame rate
  s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_QVGA);

#if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_WIDE)
  s->set_vflip(s, 1);
  s->set_hmirror(s, 1);
#endif

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  startCameraServer();

  Serial.print("Camera Ready! Use 'http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("' to connect");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(10000);
}
```

Comment: `Brownout detector was triggered` Did you look into what the brownout detector is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message:

> Brownout detector was triggered

is being generated by your ESP32 because there is a problem with the Vcc power to the module.

Check the following:

1. Your USB cable.  Some cables are just plain cheap and can't supply the power the ESP32 needs.  Get a better one.
2. Some PCs are not able to supply enough power from their USB ports to supply the ESP32, try a powered USB hub and/or a different PC.
3. Some ESP32 modules are poorly made and may have bad solder joints or low quality components.  Your only real option here is to buy a better ESP32.
4. If you are powering other components from the ESP32's power supply, stop it.  Power any accessories separately.

Comment: I am connecting to the esp32 directly via ftdi. I tried both 3.3v and 5v and tried putting a 470uf capacitor right next to the vcc thinking it needed a bypass. I got zero change. The ftdi device is connected to a powered USB hub. I am not trying to power any other components. Joints look fine.

Comment: For... here, I'll vote it up.

Comment: "Directly" is not the word I'd have used with an FTDI but where is the power for the ESP32 coming from?  Via USB through the FTDI.  So everywhere I said "USB" you can change to "FTDI".  It's still via USB.  Try powering the ESP32 directly, that is with a known good power supply.  And the part about having a bad ESP32 still applies too.  Many of these are poorly made.

Comment: I've come across this issue and I've had good results with a 10-100uF capacitor directly between the GND and 3.3V pins on the ESP32Cam board. It stopped random reboots.

Comment: I used a different ftdi and it worked. You were dead on it. Thank you.

Comment: @brad Glad to help.